# Hover tooltip show detail jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have one view that display the brief detail of the product, and then I want to use mouse over and then show its detail that return from my url action by ajax and asp.net mvc. I found [this site](http://rndnext.blogspot.com/2009/02/jquery-ajax-tooltip.html) but I don't know how to implement it. Does any one have the sample of that? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following link https://github.com/rrrene/tipsy.hovercard

hovering over link for instance will read ajax url from html5 data attribute data-url and shows the content of url in hover card.

```
<a href="some.html" rel="hovercard" title="loading..." data-url="someInfo.aspx?productId=1">Hovercard w/ AJAX Flavour</a>
```